# force ios app to update resources in new version

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm releasing a new version of an Ios App, and i'm using some new images with the same name as the old ones. But when i install the new app, in a device that had the old one, it's using the old images. 
Is it possible to force the app to use the new images (using the same images names)?

Comment: Are these images in the apps main bundle?

Comment: If the images are in the main bundle, they should automatically work.

Comment: yes, the are. If i uninstall the app, or change the images' name, it works

Comment: Did you do a `Clean` and `Clean Build Folder` before you run the project from Xcode.

Comment: I did a Clean. I haven't heard of Clean Build Folder before. Is it different?